# node_load not show taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

i dont know why

the script node_load(7) output is :

```
public 'field_tags' => 
    array (size=1)
      'und' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'tid' => string '2' (length=1)
          1 => 
            array (size=1)
              'tid' => string '3' (length=1)
```

why the field tags not filled with tag title ! it only shows tid's

does this is a normal behavior of Drupal node_laod that it only load's primary id's of relational contents like taxonomy terms 
?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the correct and expected behaviour. Loading every entity referenced by a node every time it loads, could potentially get very heavy on the server very quickly. That's why referenced entities are lazy-loaded (albeit manually as far as core is concerned).

To load taxonomy term entities from the tid, you can use [`taxonomy_term_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7). If you want an (arguably) slightly more pleasant experience when working with entities/fields on code, check out the [`EntityMetadataWrapper`](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers) class, which is part of the [Entity API module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity).